# Extract Q&A pairs from the XML stackexchange dumps

Tags: mysql, ruby, xml, sqlite

I am wanting to extract the question/answer pairs from https://archive.org/download/stackexchange, specifically from the `Posts.xml` file from any of the dumps (I randomly chose the `Anime` dump as it was fairly small and close to the top). My understanding of how this file is layed out is that there are two `PostTypeId` types, `1` being the question (includes the body of the question, title, and other meta data) and `2` being the answer (includes score, the body of the answer, and other meta data).

The data relates easily enough where if we have an entry such as

```
  <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="8" CreationDate="2012-12-11T20:37:08.823" Score="69" ViewCount="22384" Body="&lt;p&gt;Assuming the world in the One Piece universe is round, then there is not really a beginning or an end of the Grand Line.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;The Straw Hats started out from the first half and are now sailing across the second half.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Wouldn't it have been quicker to set sail in the opposite direction from where they started?     &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="21" LastEditorUserId="1398" LastEditDate="2015-04-17T19:06:38.957" LastActivityDate="2015-05-26T12:50:40.920" Title="The treasure in One Piece is at the end of the Grand Line. But isn't that the same as the beginning?" Tags="&lt;one-piece&gt;" AnswerCount="5" CommentCount="0" FavoriteCount="2" />
```

The corresponding answer would be:

```
  <row Id="8" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="1" CreationDate="2012-12-11T20:47:52.167" Score="60" Body="&lt;p&gt;No, there is a reason why they can't. &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Basically the &lt;a href=&quot;http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/New_World&quot;&gt;New World&lt;/a&gt; is beyond the &lt;a href=&quot;http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Line&quot;&gt;Red Line&lt;/a&gt;, but you cannot &quot;walk&quot; on it, or cross it. It's a huge continent, very tall that you cannot go through. You can't cross the &lt;a href=&quot;http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Calm_Belt&quot;&gt;Calm Belt&lt;/a&gt; either, unless you have some form of locomotion such as the Navy or &lt;a href=&quot;http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Boa_Hancock&quot;&gt;Boa Hancock&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;So the only way is to start from one of the Four Seas, then to go the &lt;a href=&quot;http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_Mountain&quot;&gt;Reverse Mountain&lt;/a&gt; and follow the Grand Line until you reach &lt;em&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Raftel&quot;&gt;Raftel&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/em&gt;, which supposedly is where One Piece is located.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;https://i.stack.imgur.com/69IZ0.png&quot; alt=&quot;enter image description here&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="15" LastEditorUserId="1528" LastEditDate="2013-05-06T19:21:04.703" LastActivityDate="2013-05-06T19:21:04.703" CommentCount="1" />
```

Where inside the first xml snippet `PostTypeId="1"` indicates that this row is a question and `AcceptedAnswerId="8"` indicates the `Id` of the answer. And in the second xml snippet we have the `Id="8"` being the `AcceptedAnswerId` from the question, `PostTypeId="2"` indicating that this is an answer, and `ParentId` being the questions `Id`.

Now with this being said how could I easily poll this data for the question/answer pairs. Ideally it would be useful if I could convert this to a SQLite3 or Mysql database where I am familiar with these kinds of data structures. If that is not possible (either through the database functions itself or through a scripted wrapper to populate the database) how would I parse this data in `Ruby` so that I can go through the entire XML document extracting the `title` and `body` of the question, then pair it with the appropriate `answer` body.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange Creative Commons Data Dump *is* just a (sanitized) dump from the Stack Exchange production Microsoft SQL Server database. So, considering that the data came from a SQL database and truly *is* relational data, you can import it back into one.

The database schemata are described in the [Data Dump's README](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/readme.txt), and you can find some old scripts for importing it into a database on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26956/2988). Of course, if all you want is SQL-like relational query interface, you could just use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I am not looking for an interface online since I want to scrape all the data dumps Q&A pairs and other data for a project. This requires a way for myself to take the data from the dumps and store it in a way I can easily access it like how I described. I will take a look at trying to import it back into a DB. Thanks again.